# Call a rails method from a class outside of MVC pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a news feed application that consumes an XML feed for later use.

I am struggling to get the app to call a method I have written inside of a class outside of the default Rails folders. How can I load this class into the app for use in a controller (for example)? I've read a bunch of questions on SO, resulting in the following structure / code.

My understanding is that with the following I shouldn't need to `require 'fetch_feed.rb'` from the controller or place anything in the lib folder. I am however getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `fetch_news' for FetchFeed:Class):
```

app/controllers/v1/news_items_controller.rb:18:in `index'

I am trying to call a method from the `FetchFeed` class

**Folder Structure**

```
- app
    - controllers
    - retrievers
        - fetch_feed.rb
```

**fetch_feed.rb**

```
class FetchFeed

    def fetch_news
        // Code here
    end
end
```

**aplication.rb**

```
module FeedReaderApi
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/app/retrievers)
    // Other code
  end
end
```

**news_item_controller.rb**

```
class V1::NewsItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    FetchFeed.fetch_news
  end

end
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
FetchFeed.new.fetch_news
```

`fetch_news` has been defined as an instance method. So you need an instance of `FetchFeed` to call the `fetch_news` method.

To make `FetchFeed.fetch_news` work, define it as a class method like below:

```
class FetchFeed
   def self.fetch_news
    // Code here
   end
end
```

OR

```
class FetchFeed
  class << self
    def fetch_news
     // Code here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect. You've been updating the answer before I have the chance to ask a follow up. Are you psychic?

Comment: @tonyedwardspz not yet :)

Comment: Haha. Thanks anyway, I'll accept when the timer runs out. But you knew that already......